# CSS :visited selector does not make any change?

Tags: html, css

`a:visited` selectors are not making change at all. I've read many places even stackoverflow solutions about ordering LVHA(link>VISITED>HOVER>ACTIVE). Also I read some modern browsers doesn't allow :visited for security purpose, I'm not sure though. My below code isn't working :(

```css
.anchor-list li a {
  color: orange;
}
.anchor-list li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
.anchor-list li a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}
.anchor-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: yellow;
}
.anchor-list li a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="anchor-list">
  <li><a href="http://google.com">All games</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Online action games</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Two players game</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Most popular games</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Educational games</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They are working fine for me. What browser are you using, and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: For me, using Chrome 53 on Mac, underline is only working for hover and active. a:visited has turned the links green when I clicked on them, but they're not underlined.